# Git rebase and signed commits

Tags: git, version-control, sign

Let's assume a git repository where the following hold true:

- Most commits are signed.
- Rebases are often used, so as to have a clean history.
- Sometimes multiple persons work on the same branch.
- Signing a commit is assumed to mean signing the equivalent diff, not signing the entire state of the repo (despite signed commits also signing hash of ancestors)

Now, I want to rebase a branch where I did part of the work and a co-worker pushed some commits ; and I'd like to "keep" signatures on the commits I made (ie. re-sign all commits I made with the new history, even in case of merge conflict), but not to sign work not written by me (ie. I prefer losing signatures on commits from my coworker than signing them).

I could use `git rebase -S` (like proposed in answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18874281/how-to-retain-commit-gpg-signature-after-interactive-rebase-squashing/29263454)) ; but that would also sign commits from my co-worker.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that this is a hacky answer, You should strongly consider [Cupcake@ answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18875313/1573542) as a blocker for what you're trying to do. (even if you only sign the "diff" introduced by a commit, what happens if you have a conflict during the rebase ? who signs the code introduced by the conflict resolution ?)

That said, what you could do is rebase, loose the gpg signatures. And then with `git filter-branch` do [some magic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4494037/1573542) to re-gpg-sign the commits authored by you with your key, and the commits authored by someone else with their key.

Comment: This seems to point to the direction of just accepting that the history is not 'clean', and using signed merges instead of rebases.