# Pre-verified commits arent verified on push branches

Tags: github, branching-and-merging

I am confused on how to comply with branch protection rules in GitHub that were recently established.
The relevant rules are:

- Require signed commits.
- Require a pull request before merging.

Say `qas` branch has those rules and I am working in `dev`.

I found out how to do a rebase interactive in order to verify the previous commits; and I've done that in `dev` branch.

However when I go to Github and do a pull request from `dev` to `qas`, it will still reject the commits because they aren't verified.

I do understand that it is not recommended to rebase branches that have already been published.
But I'm willing to bypass this recommendation for the purpose of verifying the commits.

Yet I am stuck when doing a pull request to `qas` because it says the commits aren't verified even though I can see they are verified in `dev` branch.

Does anyone know how I can go about this?

Thank you.

Comment: When you rebase, you undo the original signature of the commits, so you would have to sign the rebased commits yourself I believe. Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29263454/3216427

Comment: @torek right, thanks for the clarification.  Unfortunately, I cant edit my post .

Comment: @Diego-MX: I switched Git to GitHub in the text (I've gained the "edit" privilege here on StackOverflow) so I'll snip out my other comment now.